# list-style-type can be set to NONE in CSS3?

Tags: css, w3c-validation

I'm validating this CSS via [W3C validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input):

```
#breadcrumbs {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

and getting this output:

```
Value Error : list-style-type none is not a list-style-type value : none
```

What's wrong with value `none` here?

Comment: Can I see your entire source code?

Comment: This is the entire source code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `list-style-type: none` is valid in CSS3, as in CSS 2.1. This applies both to the most recent [working draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-lists/#marker-content) as well as the current [editor’s draft](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-lists/#list-style-type) of the CSS Lists and Counters Module Level 3.

But the validator has a bug here; it was reported just two days ago: [Bug 19927](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=19927) - list-style-type does not validate. It seems that the bug is more extensive than originally reported; even `list-style-type: disc` fails!

The validator bug does not affect browser behavior of course. You can keep using `list-style-type: none`.

**Update:** The validator bug has now been fixed.

Comment: The Jigsaw validator is breaking in more ways than imaginable. I don't use it anymore - I now rely on consulting the spec and manually reading my code to validate it.

Comment: @BoltClock, the W3C CSS Validator has its flaws, but there’s really no better option. The htmlhelp.com CSSCheck was good, but it is grossly outdated (CSS 1 plus some CSS 2!). CSS error reporting in browsers is useful, but it relates to what the browser can handle, not the specs.

Comment: The validator bug has been fixed 13 Nov 2012, with the comment “this was a temporary issue while making the css3 implementation
up to date”.

Comment: I hope this means they fixed the numerous other bugs e.g. with `box-shadow`, and RGBA values :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why, but try this instead:

```
#breadcrumbs {
  list-style:none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

That should validate fine and `list-style` has the same effect.